# An "almost" metric via a generalized definition of absolute values

Tags: metric-spaces, abelian-groups, absolute-value

I tried to analyse the properties of $\mathbb R$ that allow us to define the absolute valuation on it, namely
$$x\mapsto |x|\text.$$

I realised that the only relevant properties of $\mathbb R$ here are that it is an *ordered abelian group*, by which I mean an abelian group $(G, +)$ such that $x < y\implies x + z < y + z$. On such a $G$, I can define $|\cdot|$ in the exactly same manner:
$$
|x| := \begin{cases}
x, & x\ge 0\\
-x, & x < 0
\end{cases}\text.
$$

Then the standard properties of $|\cdot|$ are easily proven:

1. Positive definiteness
2. Preservation under negation
3. Triangle inequality.

Now we can define
$$ d(x, y) := |x - y|\text.$$

Then it just "begs" to be considered as a metric—the only thing being violated being the requirement that $d(x, y)\in[0, 1)_\mathbb R$.

This motivated me that $[0, +\infty)_G$ (the set of all non-negatives of $G$) could as well be used in place of the usual $[0, \infty)_\mathbb R$ in the definition of metric on sets, and possibly many other places.

Is there a part of math that addresses this kind of questions? Is there something interesting that has been done in this direction?

---

PS: Is MathOverflow better suited for such a question?

Comment: Relevant: [Necessity of the use of reals in the metric definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4159545/13130) AND [A generalization of metric spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/q/363802/15780) AND [A generalization of metrics taking values in partial orders](https://mathoverflow.net/q/409086/15780).

Answer (score 3):

If you stare at the metric space axioms carefully you can see exactly what is being used about $[0, \infty)$ that allows us to state them: all we need is the operation $+$ and the order $\le$. So we can actually state the metric space axioms for a metric taking values in a *partially ordered monoid*; there is actually no need to require the operation to be commutative, nor is there a need to require that the order be total, nor is there a need to require that the monoid be embeddable in a group; see e.g. [quantales](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quantale) and [quantale-valued metric spaces](https://www.google.com/search?q=quantale-valued+metric).

If you keep taking this perspective further you'll arrive at Lawvere's insight that [metric spaces are a type of enriched category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metric+space#LawvereMetricSpace), and the partially ordered monoid can be further generalized to a [monoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category#InMonoidCat) or even more generally than this.

I am not really aware of any useful applications of this point of view to analysis, though. The most general thing that looks like this that I know of is [valuation rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_ring), which use a totally ordered abelian group.